# PHP, If/Else statement shows condition even if I have not provided inputs yet

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this form i which I supposed to enter a number but when I run the code it already displays the event of the first condition even if I had not yet typed a number.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First number:</td><td><input type="text" name="numberone"></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
@$one = $_POST['numberone'];
@$two = $_POST['numbertwo'];


if ($one<"10")
{
echo "Have a good morning!";
}
else if ($one<"20")
{
echo "Have a good day!";
}

?>
```

Comment: what are you expecting? If you don't enter a number, `$one` (why are you using the `@` to surpress the error you are getting btw) is not set. Then you check if "nothing" is smaller then the string 10....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the form has been submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['numberone']) && isset($_POST['numbertwo'])){

    $one = (int)$_POST['numberone'];
    $two = (int)$_POST['numbertwo'];

    if($one < 10){
      echo "Have a good morning!";

    }elseif($one < 20){
      echo "Have a good day!";
    }

}
```

Don't suppress errors with `@`, because you won't see notices, which in this case would have helped you spot the problem :)

Comment: Without using default values like 0, this is the only correct answer. If the one and two statements don't belong to each other, they both should be wrapped with the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because `nothing` is less than 10. Change your condition to

```
if ($one<10 && $one>0)
{
echo "Have a good morning!";
}
else if ($one<20 && $one>=10)
{
 echo "Have a good day!";
}
```

Also, this

```
@$one = $_POST['numberone'];
@$two = $_POST['numbertwo'];
```

should be

```
$one = intval($_POST['numberone']);
$two = intval($_POST['numbertwo']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking against a string check it as a number

```
 if ($one<10) {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use `@` to suppress errors and you will need to check if the form has been submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['numberone'])
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$one = isset($_POST['numberone']) ? (int)$_POST['numberone'] : 0;
$two = isset($_POST['numbertwo']) ? (int)$_POST['numbertwo'] : 0;


if ($one > 0 && $one < 10)
{
   echo "Have a good morning!";
}
else if ($one > 0 && $one < 20)
{
   echo "Have a good day!";
}

?>
```

Do it in the proper way, don't hide the errors with `@` sign

Answer (score 1):

That is because this code all runs immediate when the page is loaded. When it is loaded the $one variable will have value 0 and so the first condition is true. I would suggest you either use javascript and use an onClick() script when the button is clicked to show a user a response based on field value, or you need to surround the if/else statement with

```
if(isset($_POST['numberone'])){
    $one = $_POST['numberone];
    if ($one < 10){
        etc
    }
}
```

This checks the value is actually set to the value from the input field to ensure it isn't executed prematurely.

Also, comparisons with literal numbers don't need surrounding by quotation marks,
just $one < 10 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if the variable is set with the isset function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php